# R e1071 predictions differ from libsvm

Tags: r, svm, libsvm

I'm trying to reproduce result that I get in R using pure libsvm.

First I've tried to export my model with `write.svm` function.
I've got model file and scale file. I've scaled my test data with `svm-scale -r model_file test_data` and then applied `svm-predict`.
But results that I get in R and in libsvm was different.

Then I tried to train libsvm with my train data and again I have predictions different from e1071 does.

Can someone help me?

P.S. I'm using eps-regression type of svm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in scaling, scale functions differ in R e1071 and libsvm.
So I have descaled data in R and then scaled it back with libsvm. So it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a random sample for training? Is the e1071 libsvm implicitly using one? If so, does the seed match your sample?